# Which version of JRuby to use with a legacy project running rails 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I have a legacy project using Rails 2.3.5 but I can't find with which version of JRuby it was running. Warble has been used to create a war file. So the only thing I see is:

```
rack-1.0.1.gemspec
rails-2.3.5.gemspec
rake-0.8.7.gemspec
```

Is there a way to know which version of JRuby was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there actually is - warbler "embeds" JRuby, just take a loot inside the archive: **.war/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-x.x.x.jar** (or **jruby-stdlib-x.x.x.jar**) where *x.x.x* corresponds to the ruby version used when the war is deployed e.g. "1.5.6"

Rails 2.3.x series were compatible with Ruby 1.8.7 thus you should be fine with the latest JRuby (1.6.7) anyway - as it is 1.8.7 compatible :

```
jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.6.0_24) [linux-i386-java]
```